# vim syntax highlight match group doesn't match with all cases

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin

I try to create a syntax highlight match group that match all words only with capital letters with underscores (constants in Java).

My definition:

```
syn match javaConstants "[A-Z_]\{2,}"
```

works with the following cases:

```
public static String HELLO = "dasdsa"
String test = HELLO;
HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
```

but fails with:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Student>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Cases with above `javaConstants` group:

[image: Cases with above javaConstants group]

Comment: `javaConstant` or `javaConstants`? Also, [your example works, here](https://i.imgur.com/xvO0RmX.png), so you are probably doing other things that we don't know about.

Comment: Hi romainl. 
it is `javaConstants`. I edited my question to correct it.
I tried to change the name and not confuse it with `JavaConstant` in the default java.vim syntax, but didn't work
I don't know what happen because when I use `:match StatusLineTerm /[A-Z_]\{2,}/` work well with all cases.
Maybe it is related with my system or vim.